# Matplotlib directory error in anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, certificate, jupyter

Matplotlib has been uninstalled, but the error below is still there. I would like to reload matplotlib, but then I get an error that says certifi cannot be uninstalled. I'm somewhat new to using anaconda and have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.1.0-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
exec(line)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 580, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored

Answer (score 0):

where is your sample code, without that not possible to suggest here.
Try re-install Matplotlib with Anaconda prompt

```
>conda install matplotlib
```